# animate() not firing until scrolling stops

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, jquery-animate

### **The goal:**

I want my fixed header element to slide up off the screen (effectively hide) when the user scrolls down, and move back down when the user scrolls up.

### **The problem:**

The actual animation and logic is working properly, but the animation doesn't begin until the user stops scrolling, as opposed to beginning while the scrolling is still going like it should.

This is replicated on Chrome and Firefox. However, with the exact same code, the solution seems to work properly in a JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/8cj7v6n5/

### Javascript:

```
var lastScroll = 0;
var scrollDelta = 10;
var animating = false;

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    //if animation isn't currently taking place, begin animation
    if (!animating) hasScrolled();
});

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(window).scrollTop();

    //if user hasn't scrolled past scrollDelta, do not animate yet
    if(Math.abs(lastScroll - st) <= scrollDelta)
        return;

    animating = true;

    if (st > lastScroll && st >= 0){    // Scroll Down
        $('header').animate( { top: -80 }, { queue: false, duration: 500, complete: function() { animating = false; } });
    }
    else {  // Scroll Up
        $('header').animate( { top: 0 }, { queue: false, duration: 500, complete: function() { animating = false } });
    }
    lastScroll = st;
}
```

Comment: Why not do this with CSS instead of javascript?

Comment: @JackAllan I tried using the `transition` property in CSS and it didn't work. Is that what you mean?

Comment: I mean rather than animate the header, just use CSS to glue it to the top of the viewport... Assuming of course that that is what you want to acheive

Comment: @JackAllan It is fixed using CSS; that's not the issue. Sorry if I didn't explain well enough. I want to slide it **off the screen** when the user scrolls down, and then slide it back on to its original position when the user scrolls back up. Think about an address bar hiding when you scroll on a mobile browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using animating flag, you can just queue the animations and use [stop()](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) with animate() to run the last animation in queue.

EDIT: you can use the flag for direction to detect if there is change in direction of scrolling.

JavaScript:

```
var lastScroll = 0;
var scrollDelta = 10;
var animationDirection = 0; // 0 for up direction, 1 for down direction

$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    hasScrolled();
});

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (Math.abs(lastScroll - st) <= scrollDelta)
        return;

    if (st > lastScroll && st >= 0 && animationDirection == 0) {    // Scroll Down                                    
        $('header').stop().animate({ top: -80 }, 500);
        animationDirection = 1;
    }
    else if (st <= lastScroll && st >= 0 && animationDirection == 1) {  // Scroll Up
        animationDirection = 0;
        $('header').stop().animate({ top: 0 }, 500);
    }
    lastScroll = st;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8cj7v6n5/27/

Comment: Thanks for the answer; however, that won't be ideal because it would stop a currently running animation midstream even if the new animation is in the same direction. Your fiddle exemplifies this.

Comment: In that case, you can use the flag for direction of animation. Edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be very close! Before I accept, there does seem to be a small lag still (not due to the `scrollDelta` number) before the animation fires, after scrolling begins. Do you have any thoughts on why that is? I know that's a vague question...

Comment: If I log in console, it shows that animation starts instantly. You may want to play around with the duration of animation and [easing effect](https://jqueryui.com/easing/) for fixing the apparent lag.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the value you use for the lastscroll is only updated when the animation happens. It should be updated always because you can scroll the screen while the animation is running and the lastscroll value will be different than the real top scroll value, then you compare the values again and the system thinks is is higher or lower than it really is.

Example:

1. Window scrolltop is 0 You scroll down -> first animation
   fires,Window scrolltop at this time is 100 and it is assigned to the
   variable st.
2. You keep scrolling down -> flag is on, animation does
   not fire, Window scrolltop at this time is 200 but it is not
   asigned.
3. First animation ends -> st is assigned to lastscroll (100)
4. Next action you scroll up, lastscroll is 100, real scroll top is
   actually 200. New scroll top is 190 but when you compare to lastscroll the systems believes you are scrolling down.

This is the corrected code:

```
var lastScroll = 0;
var scrollDelta = 10;
var animating = false;

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    //if animation isn't currently taking place, begin animation
    if (!animating) {hasScrolled()}else{lastScroll = $(window).scrollTop();};
});

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(window).scrollTop();

    //if user hasn't scrolled past scrollDelta, do not animate yet
    if(Math.abs(lastScroll - st) <= scrollDelta)
        return;

    animating = true;

    if (st > lastScroll && st >= 0){    // Scroll Down
        $('header').animate( { top: -80 }, { queue: false, duration: 500, complete: function() { animating = false; } });
    }
    else {  // Scroll Up
        $('header').animate( { top: 0 }, { queue: false, duration: 500, complete: function() { animating = false } });
    }
    lastScroll = st;
}
```

This is the fiddle I used to debug with the console logs:
https://jsfiddle.net/8cj7v6n5/18/

**Edit:**
This code works for me outside fiddle, try it if it works then the problem is in another component of the page not published here.
Maybe it is another line of code or library overriding the behavior of .animate() or the scroll event.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
var lastScroll = 0;
var scrollDelta = 10;
var animating = false;

var lastScroll = 0;
var scrollDelta = 10;
var animating = false;

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    //if animation isn't currently taking place, begin animation
    if (!animating) {hasScrolled()}else{lastScroll = $(window).scrollTop();};
});

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(window).scrollTop();

    //if user hasn't scrolled past scrollDelta, do not animate yet
    if(Math.abs(lastScroll - st) <= scrollDelta)
        return;

    animating = true;

    if (st > lastScroll && st >= 0){    // Scroll Down
        $('header').animate( { top: -80 }, { queue: false, duration: 500, complete: function() { animating = false; } });
    }
    else {  // Scroll Up
        $('header').animate( { top: 0 }, { queue: false, duration: 500, complete: function() { animating = false } });
    }
    lastScroll = st;
}
  </script>
  <style type="text/css">
  body {
    height: 2000px;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(http://static.tumblr.com/cc2l8yc/qa8nbkd68/2.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;
  }

  header {
      height: 80px;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: red;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
  }
  </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header></header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! That makes total sense, and your fiddle seems to work properly, but the same code is producing the same (erroneous) result I was getting originally, where the animation doesn't fire until the scrolling stops, regardless of how far I've scrolled. Any thoughts as to why my window would behave differently than the fiddle's window?

Comment: I cannot reproduce that issue. Check the update to the answer.